# how to write CHAR_LENGTH sql query in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I would like to write this **sql query**

`SELECT count(*) FROM menu WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(CONTENT) > 20;`

into **Codeigniter query** , How to write? Please help.

I am trying to write the above sql query with the below query.

```
  public function record_count() { 
     $this->load->database(); 
     $this->db->where('parent_id >','0');
    // $this->db->where('content>','20');   //if the field "content" is greater then 20 characters
     $this->db->from('menu');  
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the MySQL [**`LENGTH()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_length) function there:

```
$this->db->where('LENGTH(content)>','20');
```

It may be possible that codeigniter have an internal function that will automatically add LENGTH when you use the signs `>` and `<` on a string column however I cannot affirm as I am not a codeigniter expert and **I also doubt it does that so I would tell u to stick with the above.**

**Keep in mind that if your content start with a number its also possible that MySQL is matching the number against it so let's say your content start with `21` then it will be match.**

[**As you can see here in this sample it's not a common habit on MySQL itself**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82dde/2/1)

Comment: thanks, its working.  Instead of your answer i used `$this->db->where('content >','20');`  but this is also giving me the same result. THen what is the use of using LENGTH, which one is better to use?

Comment: @Danny As far as I know, [Codeigniter does not calculate](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/database/DB_active_rec.php#L398) `Length` of string by using `<` or `>` signs, these are used to compare numeric fields. by the way, SQL [`LENGTH()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) returns the length of a string in bytes, e.g. `mysql> SELECT LENGTH('text');` returns `4`.

Comment: @HashemQolami however if your text start with a number MySQL does try to match it as seen on the sample link.

Comment: @Prix That's true, No doubt, I just focused on the basic usage of `LENGTH()` and tried to clear how CI deals with `<` or `>` operators.